# Como é a base de dados de uma API que possui varios clientes

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, mongodb

Boa noite devs
estou bolando uma API, de impressão de holerites. A minha intenção é: para cada orgão/instituição que tiver interesse, eu possa criar uma base de dados só para ela.
Minha duvida é, como meu app vai saber a rota de um determinado orgão?
como devo escalonar isso? um app para consumir rotas diferentes e base de dados diferentes, há possibilidade?